# Can't delete mapi properties created through microsoft graph open extensions into outlook contacts

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a script using powershell that uses open extensions, but I didn't know there was a limit to how many open extension types(MAPI properties) I could use. Now I have reached the limit and I can't create anymore mapi properties without deleting the properties I have made previously. But I am unable to figure out how to delete thos properties.
Thanks for your help!!! :)

I have figured out a way to see them with MFCMAPI but not to delete them.
[MFCMAPI Interface with some of the properties I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkaUi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you ran out of the 65k named properties limit (the total number of mappings in a given store), your mailbox is pretty much kaput. Once a guid/id is mapped to a property tag, it cannot be unmapped.

Creating a new mailbox is pretty much the only option.