# How to completely delete custom fields / user-defined properties for a folder?

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

To use the `Items.Sort` method with a custom field, I first added a new `UserProperty` to some mailitems:

```
Set oUserProp = oSentItem.UserProperties.Add("AAA", OlUserPropertyType.olText, AddToFolderFields:=False, _ 
DisplayFormat:=OlFormatText.olFormatTextText)
oUserProp .Value = "AAA"
```

Since I used `AddToFolderFields:=False`, I then added the same property to the Sent folder:

```
Set oUserDefinedProp = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).UserDefinedProperties.Add( _
Name:="AAA", Type:=OlUserPropertyType.olText, DisplayFormat:=OlFormatText.olFormatTextText, Formula:="")
```

Then to retrieve my mailitems I used:

```
oSentItems.Sort Property:="AAA", Descending:=False
Set oSentItem = oSentItems.GetLast

oSentItems.Sort Property:="[AAA]", Descending:=False
Set oSentItem = oSentItems.GetLast
```

I made this test a couple of times, with "AAA" and "[AAA]" as property name and I also added a new column named "AAA" directly in the sent folder view from the Outlook UI.

I deleted the `UserDefinedProperty`'s in `oSentFolder.UserDefinedProperties`, and `oSentFolder.UserDefinedProperties.Count = 0`. But, in MFCMAPI, under **Sent Folder > Table > Set columns... > Property Tag Array** I can't get rid of the corresponding named properties, which apparently have both a proptag and a name in the string namespace (PS_PUBLIC_STRING property set). I tried to delete them from MFCMAPI, then click ok, but they come back each time.

From Outlook VBA I tried the following, but the properties cannot be found.

```
oSentFolder.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/AAA"
oSentFolder.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/[AAA]"
oSentFolder.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x8750001F"

oSentFolder.Items.ResetColumns
```

I can't use OutlookSpy, only MFCMAPI which does not require installation.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you delete the property from the folder fields (so that now Outlook does not recognize the property name), it might still be set on the messages.

Even if you delete the property from all messages where the property is set, the store will still remember the property mapping, so if you create a property with the same id/GUID, it will be mapped to the same int property tag.

Comment: Ok and I assume there is no way to delete those mappings? same issue than here I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935619/cant-delete-mapi-properties-created-through-microsoft-graph-open-extensions-int

Comment: Just for my personnal understanding of how MAPI is implemented in the Outlook client and stores, and of how those deleted properties still appear: MFCMAPI still sees the properties under the columns sets for the folder because they are still returned by the implementation of `IMAPIProp::GetPropList` isn't it? –

Comment: So the store provider automatically maps the named property to a proptag id using its implementation of `IMAPIProp::GetIDsFromNames`with the `MAPI_CREATE` flag to "internally register the identifier in the name-to-identifier mapping table", correct?

Comment: Ok, and do you think it would be safe to delete an entire folder like Sent, considering that on my case (fr-FR) it is named "Éléments envoyés"? Won't that mix things up too much?

Comment: I would not recommend deleting any default folders - you'd be in  world of trouble if you don't' update update properties that point to it, e.g. PR_IPM_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? MFCMAPI showing a column for that property in the folder contents table?

Answer (score 0):

To answer thoughts after Dmitry's answer, I made some tests, and is actually not the adding of a property with the `Folder.UserProperties.Add` method that makes the mapping, but the first call to the .Sort method itself using that named property!

But, it is possible to clear the mapping table for a folder in a store by deleting that folder.